# Why some sites avoid charset declaration?

Tags: html, browser, character-encoding, cross-browser

For instance, [Youtube](http://youtube.com) doesn't declare charset explicitly anywhere. Is it an unusual practice? Or it tells the encoding to browser in some other way?

Comment: This is a speculative question and far too broad – what “some sites”? It is also misguided, since YouTube declares the character encoding in HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all YouTube uses explicitly defined charset in some parts of their website. Secondly, it defines charset in HTTP header. It is more common approach when building dynamic websites, because client can obtain charset information earlier.

You can find more detailed information here: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en